# Open type sans serif fonts with true small caps

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts

I am designing the front cover page for my book in Adobe Illustrator. I would like to have a nice sans serif font for my main title. I chose Lucida Sans (font style = Demibold Roman). However, I have discovered that the small caps (SC) are only simulated and the first larger glyph looks much thicker. Doing a search on fake/simulated SC vs true SC I now understand that this font does not have true SC e.g. by looking at glyphs from Type menue.

My question is, can I download an open type Lucida Sans or similar that would have true SC? Even better I'd like to have a look at all san serif fonts that have true SC and choose the best one (out of the freely available ones - I don't want to pay for a font). A quick Google search reveals a bunch of sites to download Open Type fonts, but I don't see search function to specify sans serif + true small caps. Any suggestions appreciated!

Comment: I don't know of many free typefaces that go to the trouble of providing true small caps, but perhaps they are out there.

Comment: It would be nice if AI (Windows?) provided a way to filter fonts by categories such as sans serif + small caps. I'm looking now and there are definitely quite a few fonts you can download for free that have Small Caps. I think I might have to try them all.

Comment: Report back when you find some good ones!

Comment: @DA01 So far the search for free sans serif small caps font has yielded the following:    - http://www.1001fonts.com/sans-serif+small-caps-fonts.html - http://www.fonts101.com/search/small+cap - http://www.fontspace.com/category/small%20caps,sans-serif

Comment: Alas, based on that selection, I guess you do get what you pay for. :/

Comment: Hugely relevant: [Why purchase instead of use free?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/30372/why-would-a-designer-want-to-purchase-a-typeface-instead-of-using-free-ones) One sans font similar to Lucida which does have small caps is [FF Scala Sans](http://www.fontshop.com/fonts/downloads/fontfont/ff_scala_sans_ot_regular/ot_ps/glyphs/character_set/) but it's not free.

Answer (score 9):

Small caps in sans typefaces are somewhat rare. There are some classics available if you dig deep (and have a copy of "The Elements of Typographic Style" by Robert Bringhurst handy, which is how I originally found some of them).

The OpenType Futura issued by the [Neufville type foundry](http://www.neufville.com/nd/uk/startfuk.htm) includes true small caps and a full range of weights in both regular and condensed. They are sold [online by Bauertypes](http://www.bauertypes.com/productos/index/null/1/1?paraula=futura) (it helps if you can read Spanish). The versions sold by Adobe, FontFont, etc. *do not* include small caps.

Monotype's OpenType issue of [Gill Sans](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/mti/gill-sans/std-book/) also includes small caps.

[FF Quadraat Sans](https://www.fontfont.com/fonts/quadraat-sans) is an elegant face with true small caps.

Veer publishes [Marlowe](http://marketplace.veer.com/font/Marlowe-Family-UMT0000687?skeywords=small%20caps&stermids=100007847#), a cousin of Avant Garde, which includes small caps and an array of Avant Garde-esque quirky ligatures.

Adobe's elegant [Hypatia Sans Pro](http://www.adobe.com/type/browser/landing/hypatia/hypatia.html) has small caps, many alternate glyphs, stylistic sets and custom ligatures in a very useful range of weights. Tom Phinney drew the roman when he was at Adobe, but the Italic was added a year or so ago.

Other classics such as Frutiger, Franklin Gothic, the various Helveticas and Univers are as barren of small caps as they are of serifs.

[Later addition:] It's also worth noting that Calibri, which comes bundled with OSes, is a very versatile typeface with true small caps.

Comment: Yes, but I see that all these are not free. In any case, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Adobe Source Sans Pro has small caps in regular and semibold. It is an open source font available for free download.

[Link](https://fonts.adobe.com/fonts/source-sans)

Comment: Fira Sans by Mozilla also has small caps and is a free download.