# Are there any desktop fonts that look like integrated circuits?

Tags: font-recommendation

I´m looking for any fonts with integrated circuit aspect, similar to this image:

[image]

Or if that's not possible, could you tell me if there is a font that looks like old computers? Like in this image:

[image]

---------------------------  edited after Yisela´s answer

I like the first of Yisela, but I prefer any similar to this:

[image]

--- I always refer to FREE font. It´s for personal use.I don´t want to pay for it.

Comment: Just added paid and free options. In the future, it's better to open a new question if the edits will change the original too much (but not in this case, because there was only one answer, so it's fine). So it's helpful for other people, I edited the Free out of the title and left my answer as it is (you are looking for free, but [others might be looking for paid](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/30372/why-would-a-designer-want-to-purchase-a-typeface-instead-of-using-free-ones))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are actually a few fonts that imitate circuits and might be exactly what you are looking for (if I understood the question correctly!).

### PAID FONTS

**[Crop Circuits:](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/dingbatcave/anns-crop-circuits/)**

[image]

---

**[Boron:](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/typodermic/boron/)**

[image]

---

**[WL Circuits Circuits:](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/writlarge/wl-circuits-circuits/)**

[image]

This last one actually comes with [components](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYp4E.png) too :)

---

Now, about your second sample, that looks like **[WL Rasteroids Old](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/writlarge/rasteroids-old/)**. I found it using "old printer" as a keyword, because it reminded me of the injections printers back in the day:

[image]

---

Third sample:

**[Science White:](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/fonts-of-chaos/science-white/)**

[image]

---

### FREE FONTS

**[Circuit](http://www.dafont.com/circuit.font)**

[image]

---

**[Circuit Board](http://www.dafont.com/circuit-board.font)**

[image]

---

**[Liner BMP 14](http://www.dafont.com/liner-bmp14.font)** (old printer)

[image]